# lsode function in octave

Tags: octave, equation, dgl

I wrote the code below and it worked for several weeks without any problem.
Suddenely it stoped working with following error:

```
"warning: lsode: passing function body as a string is obsolete; please use anonymous functions
warning: called from
heun at line 23 column 2
error: 'f' undefined near line 1 column 42
error: lsode: evaluation of user-supplied function failed
error: called from
__lsode_fcn__C__ at line 1 column 40
heun at line 23 column 2"
```

The code is:

```
function yn=euler(t0,y0,tend,f,n)
t0=input('Gib hier t0 ein:');
y0=input('Gib hier y0 ein:');
tend=input('Bis zu welchem Wert von t möchtest du y annährn?');
n=input('Gib hier die Anzahl der Schritte ein(n):');
fstrich=input('Wie lautet die Differentialgleichung?', 's');
f=inline('fstrich');
dt=(tend-t0)/n;
t(1)=t0;
y(1)=y0;
for i=1:n
t(i+1)=t(i)+dt;
y(i+1)=y(i)+f(t(i),y(i))*dt;


rotdim([flip(t) ; flip(y)])
scatter(t,y,'*')
hold on
f=inline('fstrich');
t=t0:0.001:tend;
y=lsode('f',y0,t);
plot(t,y)
```

Does anyone see a mistake or something I can change?

Comment: I changed it to english. sorry for posting it in german.

Comment: “Suddenely it stoped working” something must have changed. Updated software version?

Comment: Yeah, seems like the software updated but i didnt was aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you updated octave.

```
f=inline('fstrich'); % this is discouraged
y=lsode('f',y0,t); % and this is not valid anymore.
```

Instead, make an anonymous function

```
f=str2func(fstrich);
y=lsode(f,y0,t);
```

Comment: i am getting this error: error: @y/(1+t^2): no function and no method found
error: called from
    euler at line 7 column 2
>>

Comment: @AdnZek right, because y/(1+t^2) is not valid indeed. Try `@(y,t)( y/(1+t^2) )` as input.

Comment: it works now but the plot of the solution is wrong.

Comment: but this is not the solution of the dgl with the initial value (-3/1)

Comment: Please stop spamming, I am not here for your service, I am helping you for free on my free time, be a bit mindful about that. In your code, you are trying to solve an equation for `y`. Why is then `y` part of the input you put in? would it not make sense that your input string has no dependency on `y`? I am not sure you udnerstand what you are trying to do, but if you do, can you try to explain it in the original post?

Comment: Sorry for that. I am not taking your help for granted! I tried it with another variable but it still doesnt work. Somehow the programm plots the wrong solution of the dgl. I think i understand what i am trying to do. i am solving a dgl with the euler method and then the exact solution with the lsode function.

Comment: You have not answered the question that was relevant. Why is the output, `y`, part of the equation ?

Comment: I am not sure. I dont think it makes any difference. I changed it and it still didnt work.

Comment: @AdnZek how could the equation you try to fit not make any difference? It should make *all* the difference. This is why I mean I don't think you know what you are doing

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: You seem to not be understanding what I meant at all. It has nothing to do with what I do or dont recommend, its just what you are doing does not make sense, and its your mathematical problem to solve. I cant recommend what to solve, that makes no sense.

Comment: yes, i also think i dont  unterstand what you mean. maybe because my english is not that good. but i have a master degree in math and would not say that i dont understand math. maybe if you give me a hint i would understand it better. but its okay, i dont want to waste youre time anymore. it seems like you know the solution but wont help me with it.

Comment: @AdnZek what I am trying to say is that you have a 1 variable function to solve. a 1 variable function, is defined as `y=f(t)= something_that_does_math_on_t`. For example, `f=t^2`. so your function is `@(t)(t^2)`. Yet in the only example you provided (remember, a [mcve] is a requirement for debugging help), your function is `y/(t^2+1)`, i.e. `z=f(y,t)`. That is not a 1 variable function, thus you can not fit it to the 1 variable system you want to solve. I asked what is `y`  7 comments ago and you don't seem to be able to explain. Good luck